# Action After Time with for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have this for loop that scans every grid square for the values of neighboring squares and then sets a value in a grid when i press space:

```
public void GridScan(Vector3 worldposition, int range)
    {
        GetXY(worldposition, out int originx, out int originy);
        for (int x = 0; x < range; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < range; y++)
            {
                Debug.Log(GetValue(originx + x, originy + y));
                if ((GetValue(originx + x, originy + y)) == 100)
                {
                    if (Neighbours(GetWorldPosition(x, y), 2) < 2)
                    {
                        SetValue(x, y, 0);
                    }
                    if (Neighbours(GetWorldPosition(x, y), 2) > 3)
                    {
                        SetValue(x, y, 0);
                    }
                }

                if ((GetValue(originx + x, originy + y)) == 0)
                {
                    if (Neighbours(GetWorldPosition(x, y), 2) == 3)
                    {
                        SetValue(x, y, 100);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

The problem is, the for loop would set the value before going on to the next grid square, meaning the count of neighbours with a certain value would be wrong (because some values would have changed).

Is there any way for me to set the value (The thing in the if statements) after a short period of time, and after the for loop is complete? I understand if i use Invoke, the loop will simply take the time to do the action inside the loop which is not what i want.

Comment: I for one need more context. Some code from setvalue would help

Comment: Do you really have to do this "in-place"? Because this sounds to me like simply applying a filter. And in all instances I have done that in the past, I'd have the original iterated but set values in a new grid, then return the new grid.

Comment: @Fildor Right okay this sounds promising, i do not believe i have to do the function "in-place" and i believe iterating it like that would work quite well. How would i go about iterating something like this, if you don't mind sharing? I'm quite new to programming.

Comment: You already iterate it. "Iterate" basically means you go through a collection in this context. So, what I described is like you go through a list on a piece of paper and you write the results of your computations to a list on another piece of paper, then you continue to use the new piece of paper ... Also have a look at Zohar's answer. It's quite similar. The difference is: in his solution he writes down, what you have to change and then when you are done, apply those changes to the original grid.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't go with a delay based solution on this, but with another loop to execute the `SetValue` calls once the loop that calculates all the values that needs to be set has finished.

Something like this might be a good start:

```
// Note: worldposition type is assumed to be a Position...
var newValues = new List<(Position WorldPosition, int Value)>();

foreach(var worldposition in worldpositionCollection)
{
    Debug.Log(GetValue(worldposition));
    if ((GetValue(worldposition)) == 100)
    {
        if (Neighbours(worldposition, 2) < 2)
        {
            newValues.Add((worldposition, 0));
        }
        if ((Neighbours(worldposition, 2)) > 3) 
        {
            newValues.Add((worldposition, 0));
        }
    }

    if ((GetValue(worldposition)) == 0)
    {
        if (Neighbours(worldposition, 2) == 3)
        {
            newValues.Add((worldposition, 100));
        }
    }
}
newValues.ForEach(val => SetValue(val.WorldPosition, val.Value));
```

Comment: Crud, i realise now that i've left out a pretty crucial part of code that would probably describe my problem better. Would you like me to edit this post to show you the better code?

Comment: @lachiewhitehead If you want to edit the answer to match the changed code in the question go ahead and do that. I don't mind.